# many graceful restarts in apache2 error log?

Tags: apache

The following error is repeatedly written to the apache2 error.log file.

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 23347] AH01909: mail.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23347] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

[core:notice] [pid 23347] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23347] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
```

Is this an error?
What should I do if it is an error?

Comment: If it is not happening all the time, then probably just housekeeping, see this: https://superuser.com/questions/720636/apache-restarting-graceful-restart-requested-doing-restart

Comment: thanks,
So is this not an error, is it normal?

Comment: I wouldn't look at as an error, but as a notice that your Apache restarted and if it makes sense that it would (like to rotate the logs), then no worries, if you see it all the time, it might be a symptom of a bigger problem which should reveal itself in other error logs